# Does Oracle 10g Express Edition have enough storage?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am going to develop a simple library database with less than 10 tables. Each table would only keep text records. The library has about 10,000 volumes of books and about 2,000 members.

Would the storage capacity of Oracle 10g Express Edition (5GB if am not mistaken) be enough for the library database for the next 20 years? (Assume volume of books increase at a rate of about 1,000 books per year and the number of members increase about 100 people every year).

Comment: I would assume that 5G should be enough for what you describe. But 10g is already outdated. For any new project you should use the current version which is 11g (which also has a max. size of 11GB instead of "just" 5)

Answer (score 2):

@a_horse_with_no_name is correct in recommending the 11g express and you would have more certainty that the project would not run out of room.

You should consider a proviso when you supply the database that you make no representation as to how long it can be used.  Even though you think you will only have ten tables software grows and requests to change or tinker with things never stop. For example:

- oh, we have video content now, can you do that?
- we need to have lending and borrowing audited
- our client interface needs x
- we need fast free text searching

All of these are possible but some are not advisable but they all need more tables and storage.

Also keep in mind that you are more likely to hit the limits for memory depending on how many concurrent users and the connection pooling methods used.
"[Other hardware restrictions remain the same with CPU usage capped at one physical core and memory at 1GB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-xe-quicktour-498681.html)".